# Command prompt hangs on starting mysql

Tags: mysql, command-prompt

Searched net and site but haven't found solution yet. Installed XAMPP but this wasn't visible through command prompt so installed 32-bit mysql on 64-bit machine running windows 8 manually. The problem is when I load the command prompt and type mysql the command prompt freezes and won't even close when I try to close it through the task manager. I need mysql to open through command prompt so that I can access it with java.

Comment: This seems to be more of a question for [superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: XAMPP on Window, Mac, or Linux? Makes quite a bit of difference...

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by starting command prompt and as admin and typing:
mysql -u root -proot100
where root100 is the password for mysql.